# Run javascript code after ajax load in div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

My ajax code is running very well but i want add javascript in my request file.

My code is:

```
$('#result').load('code.php');
```

This runs well but in `code.php` i put this code `<script>alert('hi');</script>` it does not give an error message or the alert.

Note : I need to write javascript code in code.php.

For some reason I need to run javascript in the `code.php`

Can any body help me?

Comment: Why not use the script like this
`$('#result').html(code);` where code is the success function from ajax. And in the ajax url put the code.php and in code.php write what you want it to show

Comment: @viper because it is the same like `$('#result').load('code.php');`.

Comment: i don't get you viper. what to want to say ?

Comment: Use a debugger to capture the *actual* complete response text from your PHP code and post that here. Then perhaps somebody will notice what's wrong.

Comment: What I was saying is that instead of loading a php file that has a javascript code inside, just use .html and ajax in order to capture the output of the php file . The output of the php file will be what the alert box will display. If what I'm saying is nonsense to you then probably I haven't understood your question :P

Comment: @viper apparently the JavaScript code to be run has some dynamic properties that are generated by the PHP code. Now, of course, there are probably better ways of doing things than to generate a script like that, but the fact is that jQuery will indeed run `<script>` blocks that it finds in content returned to ".load()". Thus, the problem is likely to be that the returned HTML is corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#result').load('code.php', function() { alert("hi!"); });
```

Now, the thing is that an inline `<script>` block in the HTML returned from your PHP code *should* run. If it's not running, I'd check to make sure that the returned HTML is not somehow corrupted. You can use your browser debugging tools to inspect the return body from the ajax call.

Comment: no, no i already use this but i don't need it, because of some variable in code.php may be dynamic

Comment: Well you did not mention that you use that in your question. As I added to my answer, the `<script>` block should work, so there must be something amiss with the overall return body from your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't relay know why it doesn't work for you but if it doesn't have a look at my answer

I think this should work:

```
$("body").load("code.php", function(data) {
    data
        .replace(/\r|\n|\t/g, "")
        .replace(
            /<script.*?>.*?<\/script>/gi, 
            function(input) {
                $("script:first").prepend(input);
            }
        );
});
```

If not try this:

```
$("body").load("code.php", function(data) {
    data = data
        .replace(/\r|\n|\t/g, "")
        .replace(
            /<script(\s.*?(src="(.*?)".*?)?)?>(.*?)<\/script>/gi, 
            function(input, match1, match2, match3, match4, match5) {
                if (match3) {
                    $("script:first").prepend(input);
                } else if (match5) {
                    eval(match5);
                }
            }
        );
});
```

Comment: None of this should be necessary. The jQuery code will run any embedded `<script>` blocks already.  If it's not working for the OP then there's simply something wrong with the response body.

Comment: I know you'r right (like I said in my first sentence) but I thought giving a suggestion is better than do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

try this as script in your php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">alert('hi');</script>
```

set type and language

edit:

my files

my setup of files was like this

test.html

```
<html>
<header>
<title>test</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
</header>
<body>
<div id="result">adasd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#result").load("test.php");
});
```

test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">alert('hi');</script>
<?php
    echo 'test';
?>
```

maybe that helps?

Comment: @micha I think the adjective you're looking for is "proprietary".